# Transfer data from one table to another table

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops

Can anybody help me to create a good way to transfer data from one table to another table?

For example:

**table1**

```
ID | Name

1  | Juan
2  | Two
```

**table2**

```
(no content)
```

What I want is a loop that will transfer the data of `table1` to `table2`. While not all data of `table1` is transferred to `table2` the loop continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard SQL approach is:

```
insert into table2(id, name)
    select id, name
    from table1;
```

You don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean to do this in VB.
Let conn, rs1 and rs2 already initialized, you can obtain your goal as shown:

```
rs1.Open "Table1", conn
rs2.Open "Table2", conn, 3, 3
Do Until rs1.EOF
  rs2.AddNew()
  rs2("id") = rs1("id").Value
  rs2("name") = rs1("name").Value
  rs2.Update
  rs1.MoveNext()
Loop
rs2.Close()
rs1.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in sql

```
Insert Into table2(id, name)
Select id, name
From table1
Where <Conditions to insert>
```

OR

```
Select * into <target_Table> 
From table1
Where <Conditions to insert>
```

> The difference between both the query is ,in first one you need to
>   create table before execute.In second one it will automatically create
>   the table.